# how can I send null select2 value to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-select2

I create a select2 for tags.

```
<select class="form-control selec2-tags form-control" multiple="multiple" name="keywords[]" style="width: 100%"></select>
```

and js:

```
$(".selec2-tags").select2({
   tags: true,
   placeholder: "type keywords...",
   maximumSelectionLength: 5,
   allowClear: true
});
```

For example I create a new content with these keywords.

I submit form  and data will send to server and save in DB.

But when I edit (update) the content and I want delete all keywords, the null value of select box does not send to server. Because it is null now!

I hope you underestand me.

How can I manage it in client-side to send select value (null or full) always?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to handle the 'change' event of select2?

```
$(".selec2-tags").on('change', function() {
   var value = $(".selec2-tags").val();
});
```

`value` will be either an array of tags or null when no tags are selected. Inside the handler you can make a call to the server to update your DB. See [here](http://jsbin.com/pozuxef/edit?html,js,console,output) to get the idea

Comment: what exactly does not work? any js syntax error? is value correct?